# SPARK | Generating too many part files

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, informatica

We have a HIVE target with storage as Parquet.
Informatica BDM jobs are configured to use spark as the execution engine to load data to HIVE target.

We had noticed that there are around 2000 part files which got generated within a partition in HDFS. This behaviour will impact the HIVE performance.

Is there any alternative for the same?

Input File Size is just 12MB

Block size is 128MB

Regards,
Sridar Venkatesan

Comment: Not a good plug for Informatica. Use Spark.

Comment: Informatica uses Spark as the execution engine, i.e it uses spark as a framework to load data to Hive target. what i would want is that, Is it a behaviour of spark to generate many part files in a partition

Comment: I know, but thay could have done a better job. They claim let us manage it.

Comment: I could see something as below : Total Inputpaths to process : 2000

Comment: Is there any way to handle this ? Setting any run time property?

Comment: I would need to know mord about the use case.

Comment: @thebluephantom: Sorry to ask more queries. What do you think had made the Spark engine which is configured in Informatica to generate 2000 files?

Comment: Difficult to comment as my Informatica days are behind me. I just know from others the product is not mature for Big Data.

Comment: @SridarV Can you add details about he Job. What kind of insert query it is etc? Sample command should be helpful.

Comment: It seems like the issue was with spark.sql.shuffle.partitions command which was set to 2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause was due to spark.sql.shuffle.partitions

Answer (score 0):

You need to set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1
This way it will not split file into multiple partitions files.
This works with huge size files as well